# Log app with reminders

Tags: applications, logging

I want to log some 1-10 parameters multiple times a day, i.e. mood, energy, hunger etc ...

After two hours of googling, I did not find a simple app that completes the following:

1. Log multiple things on a scale 1-10
2. Set multiple reminders during the day

Ideal scenario:

Let's say I set daily reminders at 10:00, 13:00, 19:00, 23:00 for hunger and happiness

at 10:00, I will get a notification/reminder. Upon rolling the screen from the top (to display all notifications), there would be two sliders, one for hunger and one for happiness.

Does this exist?

If not, anyone wanna create one with react native with me?
Will be open sourced, compensated if u wish :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with tasker.

Variables can be queried at the desired times and then written to a text file, for example.

If there are actually sliders, you probably need to design your own scene.

My recommendation is to simply try out if you can do with tasker.

To get started, there are countless tutorials. On the homepage there is one 7 days trial version.

Comment: Holy hell Tasker looks AMAZING! I have so many use cases in mind. Trying it now, thanks!

Comment: For many profiles there are already finished solutions in various forums. For the problem in your question there will be none, but perhaps for the other ideas you still have.